# Enabling CListCtrl marquee selection

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc, clistctrl

I'm using an MFC `CListCtrl` in report mode and enabled full-row selection and alpha-blended marquee selection via

```
const DWORD extendedStyle = m_wndList.GetExtendedStyle();
m_wndList.SetExtendedStyle(extendedStyle | LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);
```

Marquee selection, i.e., spanning a selection rectangle across multiple items while holding the left mouse button, works if I start the selection in the area of the `CListCtrl` window which is not occupied by items.

However, if I click on an item and want to start marquee selection from there, the selection rectangle is not created. This is in contrast to, e.g., Windows Explorer where marquee selection also works if initiated from a selected item.

As [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I've used the 'New Project Wizard' on Visual Studio 2017 and created a dialog-based MFC Application and placed a 'List Control' on the dialog resource. This list control is wired to a member variable `CListCtrl m_wndList` via DDX and gets the extended styles as mentioned above.

**ListScroll.h**

```
#pragma once

#ifndef __AFXWIN_H__
   #error "include 'stdafx.h' before including this file for PCH"
#endif

#include "resource.h"

class CListScrollApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
   CListScrollApp();

public:
   virtual BOOL InitInstance();
   virtual int ExitInstance();

   DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

extern CListScrollApp theApp;
```

**ListScroll.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ListScroll.h"
#include "ListScrollDlg.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CListScrollApp, CWinApp)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

CListScrollApp::CListScrollApp() {}

CListScrollApp theApp;

BOOL CListScrollApp::InitInstance() {
   CWinApp::InitInstance();

   CListScrollDlg dlg;
   m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
   INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();
   if (nResponse == IDOK) {
      // Do nothing
   } else if (nResponse == IDCANCEL) {
      // Do nothing
   } else if (nResponse == -1) {
      TRACE(traceAppMsg, 0, "Warning: dialog creation failed, so application is terminating unexpectedly.\n");
   }

   return FALSE;
}

int CListScrollApp::ExitInstance() {
   return CWinApp::ExitInstance();
}
```

**ListScrollDlg.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "afxcmn.h"

class CListScrollDlg : public CDialog
{
public:
   CListScrollDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);

#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
   enum { IDD = IDD_LISTSCROLL_DIALOG };
#endif

protected:
   virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);
   virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
   DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

private:
   CListCtrl m_wndList;
};
```

**ListScrollDlg.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ListScroll.h"
#include "ListScrollDlg.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

CListScrollDlg::CListScrollDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
   : CDialog(IDD_LISTSCROLL_DIALOG, pParent)
{}

void CListScrollDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX) {
   CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
   DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LIST1, m_wndList);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CListScrollDlg, CDialog)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL CListScrollDlg::OnInitDialog() {
   CDialog::OnInitDialog();

   const DWORD extendedStyle = m_wndList.GetExtendedStyle();
   m_wndList.SetExtendedStyle(extendedStyle | LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);

   m_wndList.InsertColumn(1, _T("Test 1"), 0, 200);
   m_wndList.InsertColumn(1, _T("Test 2"), 0, 800);

   m_wndList.InsertItem(1, _T("Item 1"), 0);
   m_wndList.InsertItem(1, _T("Item 2"), 0);

   return TRUE;
}
```

**ListScroll.rc**

```
IDD_LISTSCROLL_DIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 320, 200
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
EXSTYLE WS_EX_APPWINDOW
CAPTION "ListScroll"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,209,179,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,263,179,50,14
    CTEXT           "TODO: Place dialog controls here.",IDC_STATIC,10,96,300,8
    CONTROL         "",IDC_LIST1,"SysListView32",LVS_REPORT | LVS_ALIGNLEFT | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP,7,7,306,162
END
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction and explain, how to enable marquee selection that is starting from an individual item in the list control?

***Edit***: Here's an example of marquee selection from Windows Explorer in Windows 10

[image: Example of marquee selection from Windows Explorer]

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Try to reduce the width of the second column:  `m_wndList.InsertColumn(1, _T("Test 2"), 0, 100);` and click from the right side of the selection. If you click/move the selected item itself, ListView thinks you want to drag&drop the selected item. This is the same behavior in Explorer. Your ListView doesn't have drag&drop capabilities so it ignores that move.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I've added an example screencast for marquee selection in Windows Explorer that is initiated from the item itself. This is what I'm trying to achieve — starting from outside of the area occupied by items already works without problems.

Comment: Explorer uses its own inaccessible class `DirectUIHWND`. To duplicate that behavior, you can remove `LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT`. But then you don't have `LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT`! You could fix that by using your own custom draw control, to draw FullRow select manually. I don't know if there is an easier way. Also if you add `SetWindowTheme(m_wndList, L"Explorer", 0)` the behavior changes slightly, it won't initiate multi-select unless the cursor lands to the right of the first column.

Comment: Maybe you can use `IExplorerBrowser`? This would give you exact behaviour of Explorer, because it uses the same control. You can also show custom content in `IExplorerBrowser`.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I guess that using a fully owner-drawn list control would be possible. I've made some tests and it seems to work — However, going owner-drawn seems like a high price to pay to get the selection marquee. I was hoping that there was some obvious, less invasive solution to this. Anyway, thanks for sharing your knowledge here!

Comment: @zett42 Didn't know that `IExplorerBrowser` existed and yes, my preliminary tests show that it behaves exactly like Windows Explorer in that regard. In my non-MCVE im using an already heavy-customized CListCtrl with editing capabilities, in-list item reordering via drag'n'drop and much more. So I guess, I'll not rewrite everything using `IExplorerBrowser`, but keep it in mind for future projects. Thanks!